C++ Primer 5th Ed - Stanley Lipmann: Question on shared_ptr.unique() used in conjunction with shared_ptr.reset()
First we have a shared_ptr defined as below:
shared_ptr<int> p(new int(42)); 

According to the text below:

The reset member is often used together with unique to
control changes to the object shared among several shared_ptrs. Before changing
the underlying object, we check whether we’re the only user. If not, we make a new
copy before making the change:

if (!p.unique())
    p.reset(new int(*p)); // we aren't alone; allocate a new copy
*p += newVal; // now that we know we're the only pointer, okay to change this object

Question:
Shouldn't we only reset p when there's only 1 copy (p.use_count() == 1).
Here, if i read it correctly we're resetting p when p.use_count() != 1.  Seems like opposite.
Thanks for any help.

Shouldn't we only reset p when there's only 1 copy (p.use_count() == 1). Whats the point? We're the only user of that shared_ptr, why would we copy it?

If you are the only owner, it's all yours - you can modify it in place and there's no one else to notice. When there are multiple owners, and you don't want to disturb others, you need to make a copy so others may continue to use the unmodified original.

So the p.reset() is essentially creating a new shared_ptr p with its own control block? Thus this will not disturb others.

this all makes no sense in mulithreaded environment, and in fact, from a design perspective it makes no sense in single thread either

p remains the same object, but it now points to a new object AND to a new book-keeping structure for the new object.

p.reset(new string(*p)) with shared_ptr<int> p will not compile.

The various shared_ptrs scattered throughout the program are all different instances of shared_ptr that, in this example, potentially point to the same object. If there is only one shared_ptr referring to the object O, we can change O with impunity. Otherwise we want to prevent other holders of shared_ptrs from being affected by the changes made to O by one holder.
Trivial example: if there are more than one shared_ptr instances pointing to O,

P1 points to O
P2 points to O

we copy O so that the changes the owner of P1 wishes to make are not seen by the owner of P2. We will wind up with

P1 points to Copy
P2 points to O

Now that P1 is the only pointer referencing Copy, P1's holder can make changes without affecting P2. And since P2 is the only pointer to O, it can make changes without copying Oin the future, unless P2 is copied into P3 and we once again have multiple "owners" of O.
You sometimes see behaviour like this with string implementations. When you copy this kind of string, both strings save storage and time by sharing the source string's data. But if either string needs to change that data, it pays for a new copy so that it is the only one changed.
